# DateTime.ParseExact ignore first char C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, dst

I get a `string` value from a device like "`1140421164500`". I have to convert it to `DateTime` type. I want to use `DateTime.ParseExact` function. I know that I can convert it by omitting the first char manually like the following:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("140421164500", "yyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I want to avoid omitting the first char manually. I want to ignore it with a `wildcard` char in `ParseExact` function like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1140421164500", "*yyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Let me note that the first char can be 1 for daylight saving time is active, or 0 for passive. The device can send me also like "`0140101000000`".

Is there anything like that for this function?

Comment: Why can't you just remove the character with a string manipulation function before calling ParseExact?

Comment: Why not just ordinary string manipulation? i.e. take the substring of the input?

Comment: What about writing your own format provider which would recognise the `*`?

Comment: @jle i dont want it because i have a library which is doing the calculations/convertions about these strings, and i can only suppy the format string of the string value. Because of this limitation of my library, i can not manipulate the string(it is cautgh by internally). Now I see that there is no other solution insead of modifying my library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no wildcard character in [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that it can parse *every* possible character in your string.

You can add your format the first character of your string like;

```
string s = "1140421164500";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(s, s[0] + "yyMMddHHmmss", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output will be;

```
4/21/2014 4:45:00 PM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/e6RWIS)</kbd>.

Comment: @DStanley: +1, but it depends on what you define as string manipulation. Concatenating strings (`s[0] + "yyMMddHHmmss"`) is string manipulation!

Comment: @DStanley How is `s[0]` is different from `s.Substring(1)` in terms of source string manipulation?

Comment: @MattBurland Sorry, typo :)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov there is no difference.  Neither change the source string.

Comment: The answer works, but only as long as the first character in the string does not equal a date/time format character...

Comment: @elgonzo OP says: _Let me note that the first char can be 1 for daylight saving time is active, or 0 for passive_ Like I said; **There is no wildcard character that can parse every possible character**

Comment: @SonerGönül: Ah, yes... i should have spend more attention reading the question. My bad :(