# Unable to parse Oracle timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, oracle, odp.net

I have timestamp of Oracle:

```
string timestamp = "23-JUN-14 09.39.04.000000000 AM";
```

I am not able to parse it into system date time object. I used:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                String format = "yy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss:fffffff";
                string timestamp = "10-DEC-07 10.32.47.797201123 AM";
                {
                    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, format, provider);
                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp.ToString(), "dd-MMM-y HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

It is still passing error. It is working 7 f after m but not more than that. I used try `Parse`, try `ParseExact` - is there any way?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` needs a format string that *exactly* matches the input: that one does not. Consider re-trying with a correct format string. Something like `dd'-'MMM'-'yy hh'.'mm'.'ss'.'fffffff tt` would be closer (date format matches, as do separators, but .NET does not support that many fractional time digits so some processing *to truncate the fraction* might be needed (a quick test indicates no more than 7 decimal digits works).

Comment: To be a little more specific: consider only the date part: `yyyy-MM-dd` is not going to match `10-DEC-07`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23198962/328864, there is no way to skip parts of an exact pattern, so i guess you could do something like this:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string timestamp = "10-DEC-07 10.32.47.797201123 AM";
String format = String.Format("yy-MMM-dd hh.mm.ss.fffffff{0} tt", timestamp.Substring(26,2));

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, format, provider);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Not very pretty though.

Comment: can we do same thing without using substring (26,2)

Comment: Well, somehow you need to get rid of the two last digits in the seconds fraction, since .NET can't handle them. Using substring like this is one way, but you could just as well remove the last two digits from the timestamp somehow, and then you could use a simpler format-specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Once we started to use ODP.NET, we had to implement an extension like below:

```
public static T ConvertOracleValue<T>(this object value)
{
     if (value != null)
     {
          Type typeOfValue = value.GetType();

          if (typeOfValue.Namespace.Contains("Oracle.DataAccess"))
          {
              if (typeOfValue.Name.Equals("OracleTimeStamp"))
              {
                   int tempInt = 0;
                   Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStamp ots = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStamp)value;
                   tempInt = Int32.TryParse(ots.Millisecond.ToString("000").Substring(0, 3), out tempInt) ? tempInt : 0;
                   DateTime ret = new DateTime(ots.Year, ots.Month, ots.Day, ots.Hour, ots.Minute, ots.Second, tempInt);
                    return ConvertHelper.ConvertValue<T>(ret);
              }
              if (typeOfValue.Name.Equals("OracleTimeStampLTZ"))
              {
                    int tempInt = 0;
                    Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStampLTZ ots = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStampLTZ)value;
                    tempInt = Int32.TryParse(ots.Millisecond.ToString("000").Substring(0, 3), out tempInt) ? tempInt : 0;
                    DateTime ret = new DateTime(ots.Year, ots.Month, ots.Day, ots.Hour, ots.Minute, ots.Second, tempInt);
                    return ConvertHelper.ConvertValue<T>(ret);
              }
              if (typeOfValue.Name.Equals("OracleTimeStampTZ"))
              {
                    int tempInt = 0;
                    Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStampTZ ots = (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTimeStampTZ)value;
                    tempInt = Int32.TryParse(ots.Millisecond.ToString("000").Substring(0, 3), out tempInt) ? tempInt : 0;
                    DateTime ret = new DateTime(ots.Year, ots.Month, ots.Day, ots.Hour, ots.Minute, ots.Second, tempInt);
                    return ConvertHelper.ConvertValue<T>(ret);
              }

              string temp = value.ToString();
              return ConvertHelper.ConvertValue<T>(temp);
          }
      }
      else
      {
           return default(T);
      }

      return ConvertHelper.ConvertValue<T>(value);
}
```

where ConvertHelper.ConvertValue is another extension:

```
public static class ConvertHelper
    {
        public static T ConvertValue<T>(object value)
        {
            Type typeOfT = typeof(T);
            if (typeOfT.BaseType != null && typeOfT.BaseType.ToString() == "System.Enum")
            {
                return (T)Enum.Parse(typeOfT, Convert.ToString(value));
            }
            if ((value == null || value == Convert.DBNull) && (typeOfT.IsValueType))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            if (value is IConvertible)
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeOfT, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
            }

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeOfT);
        }
}
```

This worked like a charm in our test, integration and production environments.

Comment: Be careful using this code, as it is doing rounding of milliseconds. This happens if you have OracleTimeStamps with higher precision than milliseconds. If the value of ots.Milliseconds is 130.909, calling toString("000") will round this up to "131", which is very bad. Simply changing to toString() leaves it at 130, which is fine.

Comment: On further testing, I think the best is to use toString("000.000"). My last suggestion will crash on the Substring if ots.Milliseconds is 5, because it doesn't get padded. By adding "000.000" as to toString format, we avoid the rounding.

Comment: @ogrim I don't see the reason for down vote. The piece of info I gave on this answer is not wrong, neither bad. You should improve it for your own needs if you need to.

Comment: Your solution will lead to data corruption on many Oracle installations, so it is dangerous to use.

Comment: There is/was a bug in OracleTimeStampLTZ(DateTime) constructor, you need to call the full overload and cast Millisecond to a double.              Dim ots As New OracleTimeStampLTZ(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, value.Hour, value.Minute, value.Second, CType(value.Millisecond, Double))

Answer (score 2):

.NET [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) structure has a precision of tick - 100 nanoseconds - 0.0000001 of second - 7 decimal positions after the point.

Oracle [TimeStamp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330) has a precision of up to nanosecond - 0.000000001 - 9 decimal positions after the point.

---

That is why standard DateTime cannot store all possible oracle TimeStamps. And its parsing function simply fail on more precise string representations of TimeStamp.

---

**So, what could be tried:**

- Format your TimeStamps in query to some format parseable by DataTime(with loss of precision if necessary) - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm
- Or create your own more precise `CustomTimeStamp` .Net structure and parse to it manually