# Oracle RDBMS; c#; InvalidCast exception while reading a decimal value

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, oracle12c

```
  DbDataReader _dbReader = query.SendQuery(queryTxt, ref error, fromWhere) //custom method 
  string value;
  ...
  try
  {
       DateTime dateTimeValue = (DateTime)_dbReader[i];
       value = dateTimeValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
       **value = _dbReader[i].ToString();**  // culprit statement
  }
}
catch (System.OverflowException ex)
{
   // handled gracefully
}
```

If i am reading the results of a simple query like:

```
select 1, 1.4, 2/3 from dual
```

Then, code returns InvalidCastException while reading the last value 2/3
what is unknown to me is when it can convert every other decimal to string, why not 2/3?
I know it will have the maximum precison that Oracle RDBMS allows but still it is a decimal.

Added to the complexity of the problem above code is working fine with Oracle 11* client tools but the problem is only with Oracle 12c client tools. I tried to go through documentation for OracleDataAccess API, i could not find any update related to this problem.

I can add another catch block for InvalidCastException and try using GetDecimal or something like that to avoid an error, but what if the value is not a decimal and code in catch block raises an exception again.

Any thoughts/Ideas ?

Comment: You could do a .GetValue to an object reference, then check for the types you are interested in, e.g. 'if (myObj is decimal)' then cast it to a decimal etc.

Comment: SHow the declaration for "value" variable and _dbReader.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Added to the main post.

Comment: You may want to checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990166/unable-to-parse-oracle-timestamp-in-c-sharp/25483774#25483774

Comment: I am trying to understand, why is it throwing this exception when attempted to convert to string? i mean _dbReader[i].ToString();
Or when we call _dbReader[i], internally is it trying to store the value in temporary variable and ToString will be called on it, i assume this temporary variable is decimal, may be i don't know.  Any ideas what is exactly happening internally?