# (Oracle) convert date string to datetime

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, type-conversion, timestamp-with-timezone

How to convert a date string with the following format into `datetime` when running a select statement?

```
2015-06-04T02:58:00.134+08:00
```

It is stored in a column with data type `VARCHAR2`(100 BYTE).

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not a `DATE` type, it is `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Convert TIMESTAMP with Timezone to DATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089859/oracle-convert-timestamp-with-timezone-to-date)

Comment: You can have a look at how I do this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990166/unable-to-parse-oracle-timestamp-in-c-sharp/25483774#25483774)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is stored in a column with data type VARCHAR2(100 BYTE).

First of all, you should *never ever* store **DATE/TIMSTAMP** as **string**. It is a database design flaw.

Anyway, you could convert it to **TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2015-06-04T02:58:00.134+08:00',
  2                         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM')
  3                         AT TIME ZONE '+8:00' as tm_stamp
  4  FROM dual;

TM_STAMP
-----------------------------------------------------------------
04-JUN-15 02.58.00.134000000 AM +08:00

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you specify the time zone twice?

Comment: Little mistake, it must be `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM'` (without a space after time part)