# In Powershell how can I convert the date 'June 6th 2017, 08:09:05.000' to [DateTime]?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

When tried converting I received the following error message apparently because of the `th` symbols.

> Cannot convert value "June 6th 2017, 08:09:05.000" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is 
>   an unknown word starting at index 6.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest method is probably to remove those characters. I'm pretty sure you could do this with Parse or ParseExact but I would just op for remove the "th" instead for the ease.

```
$date = "June 6th 2017, 08:09:05.000"
$date = $date -replace "(\d)(th|nd|st|rd)",'$1'
[datetime]$date
```

Replace "th" etc. if preceded by a number. If you happen to have dates that do not have those characters nothing would happen so there is no risk there. It would not be safe just to remove the letters outright with `$date = $date -replace "th|nd|st|rd"` because of months like Augu**st**.

For completeness sake there is a way that you can use `parseexact()` to get this.

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact($date, "MMMM d\t\h yyyy, HH:mm:ss.FFF", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

So that works and covers the one base. If would be harder with the other number suffixes so the first suggestion is better.

Comment: You made a typo. the $date should have June 6th instead of 6

Comment: Thats naughty ;)

Comment: `\t\h` won't cover `1st`, `2nd`, and `3rd`, and since datetime formats [don't support wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23198962/1630171) or alternations (at least AFAIK), removing the ordinal indicators is arguably the cleaner approach.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I know.  ... _the __one__ base. If would be harder with the other number suffixes so the first suggestion is better._ I just wanted to add other ways. Some part of it felt like cheating to me.

Comment: @Yury The replace would work fine but the cast would fail as it should be done on each one. Not as a whole. I do not know exactly what your issue is but this might help. `[datetime[]]$dates`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works for a single string. Could you please advise why the conversion not always works for an array like this
June 3 2017, 12:18:17.000
June 6 2017, 08:09:05.000
June 6 2017, 21:35:08.000
June 6 2017, 23:32:39.000
June 7 2017, 08:27:11.000
June 7 2017, 23:21:45.000
June 8 2017, 23:43:52.000
June 13 2017, 00:37:48.000
June 14 2017, 00:07:24.000
June 14 2017, 21:29:30.000
June 15 2017, 00:24:30.000
June 16 2017, 11:41:18.000
June 16 2017, 11:41:42.000
I get: 'Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime"'

Comment: This might be worth a second question. Regardless I cannot really read code in comments. I do not know how that data is stored on your end. Did you try my last suggestion? It works for me when I cast as a datetime array

Answer (score 1):

remove the 'th' part. You can replace that with nothing and finally after removing the comma will solve your purpose to parse it.

```
$a="June 6th 2017, 08:09:05.000"
[System.DateTime]"$($a.Replace("th",'').Replace(',',''))"
```

Output:

06 June 2017 08:09:05

Hope it helps

Comment: Comma is ok for me.

Comment: @Matt: oh yes. Even i checked it now. It is taking the comma without any issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else suggested, you need to get rid of 'nd', 'th' etc., if they exist. I would use replace like this:

```
[datetime]("June 6th 2017, 08:09:05.000" -replace '(\d+)\w{2}\s','$1 ')
[datetime]("June 6 2017, 08:09:05.000" -replace '(\d+)\w{2}\s','$1 ')
[datetime]("6 June 2017, 08:09:05.000" -replace '(\d+)\w{2}\s','$1 ')
```

They all return:

```
Tuesday, June 06, 2017 8:09:05 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
$DateFull -replace "nd",'' -replace "st",'' -replace "rd",'' -replace "th",''
```

Comment: Well I am an idiot and forgot how suffixes work and didnt add the other variants. I added them now. You don't need to chain them. Also if you are replacing them with nothing then you can omit the `,''`

Comment: @Matt with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) your RegEx could also ;-) `$date -replace "(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)"`