# how to read strange datetime format in ps

Tags: powershell, datetime

i tried several times, but never worked. I try to read in the string as a datetime to convert it in the second step into another output format...

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("26th June 2017 13:38","ddth MMMM yyyy HH:mm", $null)
```

---

1. can is substitute the `th` fomatter by something generic,so i can avoid having cases including `th, st`?
2. i also tried it without the `th` but it never worked, any solution, or other method?

   `[datetime]::ParseExact("26 June 2017 13:38","dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm", $null)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Powershell how can I convert the date 'June 6th 2017, 08:09:05.000' to \[DateTime\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864607/in-powershell-how-can-i-convert-the-date-june-6th-2017-080905-000-to-datet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [a literal string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#using-the-escape-character) in your format string or escape the identifiers:

```
$date = '26th June 2017 13:38'
$format = 'dd"th" MMMM yyyy HH:mm' # or \t\h
[datetime]::ParseExact($date, $format, $null)
```

As a side-note, I was unable to replicate your #2 issue.

Comment: Here I needed `[datetime]::ParseExact($date, $format,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)` to have it working, seems to depend on the own culture. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use TryParseExact, which takes a little bit more work, but not much. And although as previous poster noted, you *can* put the literals in there, but I think you need multiple cases for the different day endings. Here's what I came up with... Note the format strings only have a single 'd' at the beginning. 'dd' would only work for two digit dates, i.e. 21st but not 1st.

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$provider = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
[ref]$parsedDate = Get-Date

$dateStrings = @('1st March 2019 13:38', '2nd March 2019 12:34', '21st March 2019 13:01', '8th March 2019 16:20', '28th March 2019 16:20', '3rd March 2019 20:20', '23rd March 2019 23:59', '2019-03-08 13:14:40')

$rdFormat = 'd\r\d MMMM yyyy HH:mm'
$thFormat = 'd\t\h MMMM yyyy HH:mm'
$stFormat = 'd\s\t MMMM yyyy HH:mm'
$ndFormat = 'd\n\d MMMM yyyy HH:mm'

foreach ($d in $dateStrings)
{
    if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($d, $stFormat, $provider, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, $parsedDate))
    {
        Write-Information -MessageData "[$d] found by [$stFormat]" -InformationAction Continue
    }
    elseif ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($d, $rdFormat, $provider, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, $parsedDate))
    {
        Write-Information -MessageData "[$d] found by [$rdFormat]" -InformationAction Continue
    }
    elseif ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($d, $thFormat, $provider, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, $parsedDate))
    {
        Write-Information -MessageData "[$d] found by [$thFormat]" -InformationAction Continue
    }
    elseif ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($d, $ndFormat, $provider, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, $parsedDate))
    {
        Write-Information -MessageData "[$d] found by [$ndFormat]" -InformationAction Continue
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Information -MessageData "[$d] not found by anything!" -InformationAction Continue
    }
    Write-Output $parsedDate

}
```

Comment: What about the `2nd` ? Otherwise +1

Comment: Oops, yep missed that one. So another elseif with a pattern of 'd\n\d MMMM yyyy HH:mm' would catch that.